# Android - Preferences API onSharedPreferenceChanged - Which way is correct?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I am using the `Preferences-API` to implement Settings into my App.
I have chosen to use a `PreferenceFragment`.

My `PreferenceFragment` contains my `onSharedPreferenceChanged` code.
However, for one of my `Preferences`, I'm not sure which way to go about achieving my goal.
The goal is: based on the TogglePreference, either enable or disable my Receiver.

Below, I have included the **2** different ways I thought to do it.
My reasoning for the two examples is #1 doesn't use `findPreference(key)` and #2 does.
So I am requesting feedback - which way is correct?

---

```
public static final String PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER = "pref_gpsStateListener";

private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefChangeListener;
...
...

prefChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged
        (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

if (key.equals(PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER)) {

    final PackageManager pacMan = 
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    final ComponentName compLocationReceiver = new ComponentName
        ("com.studio2bdesigns.testapp021019", ".LocationReceiver");
    final SharedPreferences getPrefs = 
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());

    if (getPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER, true)) {

        //  ENABLE THE RECEIVER
        pacMan.setComponentEnabledSetting(compLocationReceiver, 
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    } else if (!getPrefs.getBoolean(PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER, true)) {

        //  DISABLE THE RECEIVER
        pacMan.setComponentEnabledSetting(compLocationReceiver, 
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
}
}
```

---

**(OR)** is this the correct way to do it :

---

```
private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener prefChangeListener;
...
...

prefChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged
        (SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

if (key.equals(PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER)) {

    Preference gpsStateListenerPref = findPreference(key);

    final PackageManager pacMan = 
        getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
    final ComponentName compLocationReceiver = new ComponentName
        ("com.studio2bdesigns.testapp021019", ".LocationReceiver");

    if (gpsStateListenerPref.isEnabled()) {

        //  ENABLE THE RECEIVER
        pacMan.setComponentEnabledSetting(compLocationReceiver, 
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    } else if (!gpsStateListenerPref.isEnabled()) {

        //  DISABLE THE RECEIVER
        pacMan.setComponentEnabledSetting(compLocationReceiver, 
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    }
}
}
```

---

At first I thought Option **#1** was correct - but the reason I came up with Option **#2** is because the first example *doesn't* use `findPreference(key);` - which is the entire point of having `key` passed within `onSharedPreferenceChanged` isn't it?

**Feedback on this is greatly appreciated! Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is used to match the visual control with shared preferences. This is really a matter for preference. I prefer to use number 1 since I am not dependent on a view, and makes shared preferences your source of truth.

Comment: Thanks for the input! What I had originally done inside of `if(key.equals...` was simply put a call to its own method `public void gpsSettingChanged()` and just do the same thing as example #1 inside of it.. But wasn't sure if that was a good way of going about it, or if I should just leave all the code within the `if(key.equals...` brackets itself. Any thoughts on that? And anybody else have an opinion on my initial question?

Comment: I would recommend breaking the code out into a method.

Comment: Thanks for the input, much appreciated! I actually have another question that's related, if you don't mind giving me your thoughts? So, in my `public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment`, prior to my `onCreate` method, I have my Preference `Strings` listed.. (eg: `public static final String PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER = "pref_gpsStateListener";`).. My question is, when I need to reference and retrieve my Preference Values from within a **different** Class, should I do the same thing in each class, **OR**, should I reference is like `SettingsFragment.PREF_GPS_STATE_LISTENER`..?

Comment: I would create a class called `Prefs` and put the keys there. That way you aren't referencing a fragment in other parts of your code.

Comment: @Studio2bDesigns If you like this answer please accept it.